# Only want to displaypart of a text string

Tags: excel

I have text in an excel report in a column that shows different values like this:

```
/Home/Garden/Lawn/Seed/Water
/Home/Garden/Lawn/Seed/Can
/Home/Garden/Shed
/Home/Garden
```

I would like to add a column with a formula that would only show the part of text that comes AFTER the last "/". There are multiple lengths of string so would need to count from the end.

So I would like my column to show:

```
Water
Can
Shed
Garden
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Thansk you all very much- problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-LOOKUP(2,1/(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)="/"),ROW((INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pipe character won't appear in the strings you're trying to parse, this will work:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","")))))
```